# How to use react within Express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a website developed in expressjs/nodejs. I want to add a reactjs module to it. I added a build of reactjs app to 'client/build' in expressjs app. 'client' is declared as static:

> app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

I expect http://localhost:3002/build/ to work but it does not. It shows a blank page without errors. The network tab in developer tools show that the referenced CSS and JS files are fetched but no react components are displayed. I do not understand why this happens.

**UPDATE:**

Folder structure:

[image]

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
      <link rel="manifest" href="/build/manifest.json">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/build/favicon.ico">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <title>React App</title>
      <link href="/build/static/css/main.dd5f9b05.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/build/static/js/main.971e2482.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is you react application code bundled into one js file in build? Where is the page that references the bundled javascript if it is?  pointing to build will not load the file automatically, unless it's called indext.html.

Comment: @BlessYahu I understand your point but that is not an issue here. index.html is being loaded properly, that is why JS and CSS are being fetched.

Comment: May the downvoter please explain the reason behind downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use('/build', express.static(path.join(`${__dirname}/client`)));
```

I think you have to specify a path first?